# Why was the Triwizard cup portkey bi - directional?

Tags: harry-potter

My understanding is that a portkey is usually only one way (uni-directional) so as the title says, why make the Triwizard Cup portkey able to return back to Hogwarts (bi-directional)?

Why bother to make it go back to Hogwarts, allowing Harry to use it to go back?

Comment: An excellent first question. I've taken the liberty of tightening up the language used.

Comment: Excellent first question indeed, but unfortunately a duplicate :(